# Atom editor fails installing packages

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to install packages in Atom editor, but it always fails, just like if I coudn't get a connexion to the server.

For instance, `apm install split-diff` returns `Request for package information failed: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND atom.io atom.io:443 (ENOTFOUND)`

I'm running Atom 1.32.2 on Linux Mint 19. 
I don't use a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out where the bug was!

For some reasons of personal convenience, I replaced /etc/hosts with a symlink (towards some place in my ~/ folder). THIS is what apm didn't like. (No idea why. I'd be glad to know...) Switching back to a real file for /etc/hosts made me able to install packages again.

Answer (score 4):

Check your DNS servers.

I ran into this problem randomly this afternoon when initially everything was working on my Mac.

I can reach the Internet fine. Github is up and reporting no issues, Atom.io is up...

Clues re:etc/hosts from other comments here pointed me to my my network settings anyway.

Checked and I have my DNS servers configured for VPN access, once I added OpenDNS servers as well, Atom installs starting working again.

Comment: `ipconfig /flushdns` flushes the DNS cache, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed split-diff and it loaded fine. Open Atom and under the Atom menu item select Preferences. This opens a new window and on the left side of the pane is a row of actions starting with Core and followed by Editor, URI Handling, and 5 other actions. Click on the Install action. This is where you can find and install extensions. Once you clicked on Install, the pane changes and there is a search box at the top. In the search box type split-diff and the name of your extension should appear. There should be a blue install button for the script. Click install and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, jmh. Unfortunately, it doesn't work this way either. The process you describe is actually the first thing that I tried, and I believe under the wood it just runs the same command that I was mentioning. It also returns the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and I was having this problem. I had a directory called /etc/hosts/ which was a cloned version of [this repo](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts).

Clearly having a directory named the same as a file isn't exactly a smart move, but I was able to solve the problem through moving the directory and running the install script for the repo again. The install script calls a which flushes the DNS file, found in line 1193 of [this file here](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts/blob/master/updateHostsFile.py).

I extracted the script/function which should do the trick;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Script by Ben Limmer
# https://github.com/l1m5
#
# This Python script will combine all the host files you provide
# as sources into one, unique host file to keep you internet browsing happy.

import argparse
import fnmatch
import json
import locale
import os
import platform
import re
import shutil
import socket
import subprocess
import sys
import tempfile
import time
from glob import glob

import lxml  # noqa: F401
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Detecting Python 3 for version-dependent implementations
PY3 = sys.version_info >= (3, 0)

if PY3:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
else:
    raise Exception("We do not support Python 2 anymore.")

# Syntactic sugar for "sudo" command in UNIX / Linux
if platform.system() == "OpenBSD":
    SUDO = ["/usr/bin/doas"]
else:
    SUDO = ["/usr/bin/env", "sudo"]


# Project Settings
BASEDIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def flush_dns_cache():
    """
    Flush the DNS cache.
    """

    print("Flushing the DNS cache to utilize new hosts file...")
    print(
        "Flushing the DNS cache requires administrative privileges. You might need to enter your password."
    )

    dns_cache_found = False

    if platform.system() == "Darwin":
        if subprocess.call(SUDO + ["killall", "-HUP", "mDNSResponder"]):
            print_failure("Flushing the DNS cache failed.")
    elif os.name == "nt":
        print("Automatically flushing the DNS cache is not yet supported.")
        print(
            "Please copy and paste the command 'ipconfig /flushdns' in "
            "administrator command prompt after running this script."
        )
    else:
        nscd_prefixes = ["/etc", "/etc/rc.d"]
        nscd_msg = "Flushing the DNS cache by restarting nscd {result}"

        for nscd_prefix in nscd_prefixes:
            nscd_cache = nscd_prefix + "/init.d/nscd"

            if os.path.isfile(nscd_cache):
                dns_cache_found = True

                if subprocess.call(SUDO + [nscd_cache, "restart"]):
                    print_failure(nscd_msg.format(result="failed"))
                else:
                    print_success(nscd_msg.format(result="succeeded"))

        centos_file = "/etc/init.d/network"
        centos_msg = "Flushing the DNS cache by restarting network {result}"

        if os.path.isfile(centos_file):
            if subprocess.call(SUDO + [centos_file, "restart"]):
                print_failure(centos_msg.format(result="failed"))
            else:
                print_success(centos_msg.format(result="succeeded"))

        system_prefixes = ["/usr", ""]
        service_types = ["NetworkManager", "wicd", "dnsmasq", "networking"]

        for system_prefix in system_prefixes:
            systemctl = system_prefix + "/bin/systemctl"
            system_dir = system_prefix + "/lib/systemd/system"

            for service_type in service_types:
                service = service_type + ".service"
                service_file = path_join_robust(system_dir, service)
                service_msg = (
                    "Flushing the DNS cache by restarting " + service + " {result}"
                )

                if os.path.isfile(service_file):
                    dns_cache_found = True

                    if subprocess.call(SUDO + [systemctl, "restart", service]):
                        print_failure(service_msg.format(result="failed"))
                    else:
                        print_success(service_msg.format(result="succeeded"))

        dns_clean_file = "/etc/init.d/dns-clean"
        dns_clean_msg = "Flushing the DNS cache via dns-clean executable {result}"

        if os.path.isfile(dns_clean_file):
            dns_cache_found = True

            if subprocess.call(SUDO + [dns_clean_file, "start"]):
                print_failure(dns_clean_msg.format(result="failed"))
            else:
                print_success(dns_clean_msg.format(result="succeeded"))

        if not dns_cache_found:
            print_failure("Unable to determine DNS management tool.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a filter breaker. I had the same problem installing the file_icons package, and the package was installed when the Siphon filter breaker was connected.